# Difference between matching and perfect matching

Tags: algorithm

Consider a set M = {m1, m2, ..., mn} of n men, and a set W = {w1, w2, ..., wn}
of n women. Let M X W denote the set of all possible ordered pairs of the form 
(m, w), where m belongs to M and w belongs to W.

A **matching** S is a set of ordered pairs, each from M X W, with the property
that each member of M and each member of W appears in at most one pair
in S.

A **perfect matching** S1 is a matching with the property that each member of M
and each member of W appears in exactly one pair in S1.

I am having tough time to understand above statment on definitions of 
matching and perfect matching.

Can any one give me an example on matching and perfect matching on 
following example. M = {m1,m2, m3} and w = {w1, w2, w3}

Thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better example would be to use `M={m1,m2,m3,m4}` and `W={w1,w2,w3}`.  There is no perfect match possible because at least one member of M cannot be matched to a member of W, but there is a matching possible. An example of a matching is `[{m1,w1},{m2,w2},{m3,w3}] (m4 is unmatched)`

In the example you gave a possible matching can be a perfect matching because every member of M can be matched uniquely to a member of W.

Answer (score 2):

A matching:

```
 {(m1,w1), (m2,w2)}
```

A perfect matching:

```
 {(m1,w1), (m2,w2), (m3,w3)}
```

Comment: can u pls eloborate, here (m1, w1) and (m1, w1) appears in both sets may be stupid question then what is difference between these two

Comment: The difference is that the first doesn't contain the pair `(m3, w3)` and the second does.

Comment: @venky A `perfect match` must contain all the elements, while a non-perfect one may contain only a (possible empty) subset.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a matching: ∅. No member of *M*, nor any member of *W*, appears in more than one pair in ∅, trivially, so the definition is satisfied.

∅ is not a perfect mathing, though, since no members of *W* or *M* appear in its pairs (since there are no pairs in it).

Comment: That's not pi, that's the empty set.

Comment: @venkysmarty - If you don't understand the representation for an empty set then your understanding of set theory is very basic.